# sp_executesql not accepting multiple types

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Settings](
   [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [Key] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
   [Value] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
   CONSTRAINT [PK_Settings] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
   WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I'm trying to run this query

```
exec sp_executesql 
   N'INSERT INTO Settings ([key], [value]) VALUES (@k6,@v6), (@k8,@v8)',
   N'@k6 nvarchar(4000), @v6 nvarchar(4000), @k8 nvarchar(4000), @v8 bit',
   @k6=N'DefaultLocale', @v6=N'eb', @k8=N'ReCaptchaIsEnabled', @v8=1
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'eb' to data type
> bit.

When I remove the `bit` definition or remove `Nvarchar` definition it working well. From what I see, I cannot mix different value types in this query.

Can you tell me why?
Thank you

Comment: It's likely an implicit conversion issue. You might try separating the one insert into two separate inserts for the `6` and `8` parameters to see if that resolves the error.

Answer (score 3):

It's the same reason this doesn't work:

```
DECLARE @x nvarchar(4000) = N'foo', @y bit = 1;

SELECT x = @x
UNION ALL
SELECT y = @y;
```

Same error. If you're going to use the wrong data types (for example, `key` is `varchar(50)`, so why is `@k6` `nvarchar(4000)`?), you're going to need to massage them to prevent unexpected errors that come from how SQL Server might construct an execution plan. Try making your statement:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Settings ([key], [value])  
VALUES (@k6,CONVERT(nvarchar(max),@v6)),
       (@k8,CONVERT(nvarchar(max),@v8));
```

Comment: Thank you for this example!

Answer (score -1):

It's because that causes the SQL to do the an Implicit conversion and It cause failure , here is the way SQL server engine sees your query :
[image: estimated execution plan]

you have no way unless match the datatype before passing it
you can find out more about CONVERT_IMPLICIT warning in Pinal blog:
[SQL SERVER – How to Fix CONVERT_IMPLICIT Warnings?](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/06/11/sql-server-how-to-fix-convert_implicit-warnings/)